# How to register MessageDispatcherServlet in a classic (non Boot) Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I am currently in the process of developing a web application that is accessible via SOAP using Spring 5.1.3 with Spring-WS and have no clue how to register an additional servlet (in this case, `MessageDispatcherServlet` for Spring-WS) using Java config. I should note that this is a non Boot application.

I consulted [the official Spring docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) for help, however this guide is geared towards Spring Boot (which uses `ServletRegistrationBean`, which is exclusive to Spring Boot). According to the guide, the `MessageDispatcherServlet` is registered like this:

```java
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }
}
```

This looks nice and straightforward apart from the fact that `ServletRegistrationBean` resides in `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet` => Spring Boot => not available to me.
How do I register my `MessageDispatherServlet` in a "non Boot" standard Spring application? Thanks a lot for any hints or advice.

Comment: Just like you register all the other servlets...

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for any pointers everyone. I managed to register the `MessageDispatcherServlet` via `WebApplicationInitializer`:

```java
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebConfig.class);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        // Message Dispatcher Servlet (SOAP)
        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic messageDispatcher = container.addServlet("messageDispatcher", messageDispatcherServlet);
        messageDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        messageDispatcher.addMapping("/ws/*");
    }
}
```

Pretty straightforward once you know how to do it :D